# How to change the size of python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I change the size of the turtle in. I'm looking to decrease the size of it but

```
turtle.size("small")
```

doesn't work.
I am using a website called trinket.io/python

Comment: [shapesize / turtlesize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.shapesize) ?

Comment: did you check dokumentation ? You can also use `import turtle` and `help(turtle)`

Comment: This question may have been erroneously marked a duplicate of an answer that is not apropos.  One key detail in the OP's question is ***trinket.io/python***.  This online environment provides its own implementation of turtle.py, which is a subset of the standard one, that leaves out many features.  So suggesting `shapesize()` or `turtlesize()` does no good as they are not available in that environment.